# Configuring 2 environments with SVN and an "uploads folder"

Tags: php, codeigniter, svn, file-upload

I'll try to explain this the best I can.

I'm building a web application and have just been doing development on the production copy.  Now I'm closer to launch and I want to have a production version and a development version.

I'm currently using SVN and committing to trunk as I finish and test features.

My plan was to have my production copy just run svn update to get code as it passes testing.  This seems very straightforward.

Here's the issues - the production copy has an "uploads" folder that lets users upload photos.  The uploads folder itself is inside the codebase that is in the repo, but since the users are uploading photos how can I manage these photos if that copy of the code is only getting updates?

The way things are configured now if I was to run an update on production I'd actually wipe out the photos.

I'm guessing my options are:

1. Move the uploads folder to a place outside the repo
2. Build some kind of auto-committer from production so the uploaded photos are part of the repo.

What do you think - am I explaining this clearly enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `svn:ignore` versioned property: `$ svn propedit svn:ignore uploads`. Then enter a single `*` (wildcard) character or a list of specific file types you don't want saved in the repo, such as `*.jpg`, `*.png`, etc.

See [Ignoring Unversioned Items](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html) from the SVN book.